# How to define typescript interface for array on objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is the data from the server.

[image]

I want to display it with map on UI.

Here is the interface I did -

```
export interface IHistory {
    reports: Readonly<{
        readonly id?: string,
        status?: Status,
        readonly created_at?: Date,
    }>
}[];
```

The map I'm doing:

```
{props.history!.map((index, idx) => {}
```

The error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')

What am I doing wrong?
I want to display only the reports.

[image]

Added -

Interface -

```
export interface IHistory {
    reports: Array<{
        id?: string;
        status?: Status;
        created_at?: string;
    }>;
};

const [ hitoryState, setHistoryState ] = useState<IHistory | null>(null);

useEffect(() => {
    backendAPIAxios.get('/history')
      .then((response: AxiosResponse<IHistoryResponse>) => {
        if (!response.data) {
          return alert('Failed to get history');
        }

        setHistoryState(() => response.data);
      })
      .catch((e: AxiosError) => {
        // alert(`Failed to get history with error: ${e}`);
      });
}, [setHistoryState])

console.log(props.history!.reports.map((hist) => <p>{hist.created_at}</p>))
```

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: You're getting the error because `props.history` is undefined. Make sure you're passing the right props to that component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making IHistory an array of reports objects, when reports is the field with the array.  Also, created_at will likely be a string and not a date if it's being returned from the backend.

```
type Status = "fair" | "unfair";

interface IHistory {
  reports: Array<{
    id?: string;
    status?: Status;
    created_at?: string;
  }>;
};

const backendHistory: IHistory = {
  reports: [
    { id: "123", status: "fair", created_at: new Date().toISOString() },
    { id: "456", status: "unfair", created_at: new Date().toISOString() },
  ]
};

const result = backendHistory.reports.map(({ id }, _idx) => id);
console.log("result", result);
```

React code:

```
import React from "react";

type Status = "fair" | "unfair";

interface IHistory {
  reports: Array<{
    id?: string;
    status?: Status;
    created_at?: string;
  }>;
}

async function fakeFetch(): Promise<IHistory> {
  const backendHistory: IHistory = {
    reports: [
      { id: "123", status: "fair", created_at: new Date().toISOString() },
      { id: "456", status: "unfair", created_at: new Date().toISOString() }
    ]
  };

  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve(backendHistory), 1000)
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [backendHistory, setBackendHistory] = React.useState<IHistory>();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let isAlive = true;

    (async function () {
      const result = await fakeFetch();
      if (isAlive) {
        setBackendHistory(result);
      }
    })();

    return () => {
      isAlive = false;
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Backend History</h1>
      {backendHistory ? (
        backendHistory.reports.map((hist) => <p>{hist.id}</p>)
      ) : (
        <span>loading</span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: How can i use `const backendHistory: IHistory` it's static?

Comment: It's a readonly reference to a mutable object.  You can use it like any other variable.  Beneath that line of code is a sample use-case.  `backendHistory.reports.map(({ id }, _idx) => id);`

I also named the variable `backendHistory` over `history` because `history` has other meaning in the browser.

Comment: I'll ask a better Q how can I use it as props? I get the data from the server

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong but I can't use the backendHistory to assing the props

Comment: Added some sample react code above.  If this helps can you upvote and accept the answer.  I'm trying to get my points up.

Comment: Added the error I'm getting